# Prototype IE,Firefox,Chrome differences

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Dear all, i've got following script here (don't blame me i don't know javascript at all)

```
$$('#status').each(function(item) { 

 var state = item.innerHTML

 if (state == "ON_GOING"){
  item.replace('<img src="layout/images/ongo.png"/>'); 
 }
 if (state == "PAUSED"){
  item.replace('<img src="layout/images/pause.png"/>');
 }
});
```

which is stored at the bottom of the document. i also tried to make it 'named' and call from 'onload' parameter of 'body' tag, as well as by 'window.onload = ' statement.
But it's being displayed correctly only in firefox but not in IE or Chrome. 
In Prototype documentation it is said that it's designed for all of those browser, however i still get the issue, could you kindly tell what's wrong with this piece of code and how should i compose to make it work (to update 'status' id in html after page loads).

So basically i'd like to replace initial text in  block with image, but it's not happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not saying what the actual problem is?

Comment: The problem is that same code doesn't show same results in Firefox, IE7 and Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be browser differences as to whitespace around the string. Try stripping the returned HTML:

```
item.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/,'$1')
```

Update:

you are looking for this selector: `$$('#status')` That means you are looking for multiple objects with id `status`. I don't think that's supposed to work. Dom Id are meant to be unique. I think you should use a CSS class instead and change the selector to `$$('.status')`

Comment: I've updated the script with your string, and replaced .replace() with .update() functions... now it's ok for Firefox and Chrome but IE7 still show initial text instead of replaced image.

Comment: Update... seems that stripping of whitespaces has no effect, but using update() instead of replace() makes Chrome & FF show content correctly

Comment: SUPER! it worked thanks a lot! now it's same in IE, FF and Chrome